# How to add a title to sjmisc::frq(out = "v")

Tags: r

I have received the reccomendation to replace`sjt.frq()` with `sjmisc::frq(out = "v")` in my code. I don't know how to add a title to the table when using `frq()`.

`sjt.frq()` had the `title=` argument, eg.  `sjt.frq(var, title = c("VarTitle"))`, but `frq()` does not.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct and simple way, but I've added that option and it's available in the [current GitHub-version](https://github.com/strengejacke/sjmisc). I also slightly tweaked the method to print HTML-tables, which also affects `sjmisc::frq()` and which will be available in the forthcoming *sjPlot*-update.

So, either install from GitHub or wait some days for the updates to arrive at CRAN.

Comment: Daniel, thank you so much. Our complete syntax on Food security analysis rely heavenly in this simple command. Dont worry, we can wait for the CRAN update. Thank you again.